# How do I programmatically customize a folder's view?

Tags: mac, finder, macos

I'm a software developer who is new to mac.  I'm working on an app that exposes a lot of files through a WebDav connection.

Anyways, I'm wanting to customize the way that the folder shows up in Finder.  I have somewhat gathered that this has something to do with .DS_store files but I can't seem to find any information on its file format.  Specifically, I'm wanting to set a custom background image that Finder will render when machines display the web dav files and folders.

Comment: You want to customise for instance a .dmg so it opens with a custom view with picture... or you want to force that to happen on another user's view, sometime later? First is simple, 2nd won't happen.

Comment: @Tetsujin it's the second

Comment: I want to create a file on my webdav server that will make the folder appear differently in Finder.  I believe that I would do that by creating a server-side .DS_store folder, but I'm not sire.

Comment: I can make a Windows server have a custom background, so long as it remains open in the Finder. As soon as I close & reopen, it's gone. On Mac, copying the .DS_store file from one folder to another doesn't make the picture follow. I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23056984/set-folder-background-image-on-mac-with-python but doesn't have anything conclusive.

Comment: I'd also see the caveats at the bottom of https://diplograph.net/posts/folder_background_images